# Previously saved record can't be altered

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to let the user edit their account details if there is a problem with the account(e.g. forgotten password).
In a previous form, the user enters their email which is verified and a variable is used to mark the record number and is used to show the record in the textboxes.
If the user edits the data and clicks save, everything works. However, I can not login with the new credentials if I go to the login form.

[Design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2jrko.png)

```
Private Sub ChangeUserDetails_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'DataSet1.Users' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
    Me.UsersTableAdapter.Fill(Me.DataSet1.Users)
    AlterUsernameTB.Text = UsersBindingSource(validatedRecord)("Username").ToString
    AlterPasswordTB.Text = UsersBindingSource(validatedRecord)("Password").ToString
    AlterEmailTB.Text = UsersBindingSource(validatedRecord)("Email").ToString
End Sub

Private Sub SaveBtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SaveBtn.Click
    'Exception class will detect errors if any.
    Try
        Select Case MsgBox("Are you sure you want to alter your account details?", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo, "Are You Sure")
            Case MsgBoxResult.Yes
                If AlterUsernameTB.Text <> Nothing Then
                    If AlterPasswordTB.Text <> Nothing Then
                        If AlterReTypePasswordTB.Text <> Nothing Then
                            If AlterEmailTB.Text <> Nothing Then
                                If AlterReTypePasswordTB.Text = AlterPasswordTB.Text Then
                                    'Exception class will detect errors if any.
                                    Me.Validate()
                                    Me.UsersBindingSource.EndEdit()
                                    Me.TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(Me.DataSet1)
                                    MessageBox.Show("Your account has been altered. Please click on Back to Login.")
                                Else
                                    MessageBox.Show("Passwords do not match!")
                                End If
                            Else
                                MessageBox.Show("Email textbox is empty!")
                            End If
                        Else
                            MessageBox.Show("Re-type password textbox is empty!")
                        End If
                    Else
                        MessageBox.Show("Password textbox is empty!")
                    End If
                Else
                    MessageBox.Show("Username textbox is empty!")
                End If
            Case MsgBoxResult.No
                'If 'No' is clicked nothing will happen.
        End Select
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

What am I doing wrong?
Any help would be much appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Instead of binding the text boxes to the table and trying to save them (which was the totally wrong thing to do) I instead inserted the code below into the last If statement just before saving. It works!

```
DataSet1.Users(validatedRecord).Username = AlterUsernameTB.Text
DataSet1.Users(validatedRecord).Password = AlterPasswordTB.Text
DataSet1.Users(validatedRecord).Email = AlterEmailTB.Text
```